# ERROR: argument of OR must not return a set

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, non-ascii-characters

Running PostgreSQL 9.2.8 here...

I've been trying to obtain a list of all rows in a table that have non-ASCII characters in the address - anything outside the range of `<space>` to `~`, as well as the backtick character `` ` `` . If any of the rows contain any invalid characters, the row with all address values would display. But for some reason I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  argument of OR must not return a set (10586)
LINE 9: (CAST(regexp_matches(a.address_line_1,'([^ !-~]|`)') AS VARCHAR)...
         ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: argument of OR must not return a set (10586)
SQL state: 42804
Character: 252
```

The query I've been trying to use is as follows:

```
select a.address_id, a.address_line_1, 
    a.address_line_2, 
    a.address_line_3, 
regexp_matches(a.address_line_1,'([^ !-~]|`)'),
regexp_matches(a.address_line_2,'([^ !-~]|`)'),
regexp_matches(a.address_line_3,'([^ !-~]|`)')
    FROM public.address a 
WHERE 
(CAST(regexp_matches(a.address_line_1,'([^ !-~]|`)') AS VARCHAR) <> '') OR
(CAST(regexp_matches(a.address_line_2,'([^ !-~]|`)') AS VARCHAR) <> '') OR
(CAST(regexp_matches(a.address_line_3,'([^ !-~]|`)') AS VARCHAR) <> '')
LIMIT 1000
```

I'm not sure what I could be missing as this seems like a valid query.

I am trying to get rows where there is an invalid character in ANY of the three address fields, not just an invalid character in all three.

Comment: `regexp_matches` returns a set, conditions must be boolean, and can't be a "set" of something. You're using the wrong function in any case. If you want to see whether you have a match, do something like `WHERE a.address_line_1 ~ '[^ !-~]' OR a.address_line_2 ~ '[^ !-~]'` etc. You also don't need the `a` alias.

Comment: @eurotrash what's the `~` operator do in this case?

Comment: It does a regex comparison and returns a boolean to say whether it matches the pattern. Have a read of this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: @eurotrash it seems that using (a.address_line_1 ~ '([^ !-~]|`)') OR a.address_line_2 ~ '([^ !-~]|`)') OR (a.address_line_3 ~ '([^ !-~]|`)') works as a three-pronged AND, and not a three-pronged OR... I'm only getting the one result which appears to have an invalid character in all three address fields?

Comment: Sure, I didn't really read what exactly your regex was doing so whether it's AND or OR etc is up to you to decide, but the point is you should use `~`/`!~` to check for regex patterns in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: From the [`documentation`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP): "If two characters in the list are separated by -, this is shorthand for the full range of characters between those two (inclusive) in the collating sequence,". What's your collation? Maybe `!-~` is not what you expect it to be?

Comment: Please *always* declare your version of Postgres. And clarify the definition of "invalid characters".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[regexp_matches()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) returns `SETOF text` and cannot be used like you tried (as the error message tells you). You could use the [regular expression operator **`~`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) instead.

But your regular expression does not seem to cover what you describe as:

> non-ASCII characters in the address

Also, the range `!-~` in your bracket expression `[^ !-~]` depends on your `COLLATION` setting. [The manual warns:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-BRACKET-EXPRESSIONS)

> Ranges are very collating-sequence-dependent, so portable programs should avoid relying on them.

Consider:

```
SELECT g, chr(g), chr(g) ~ '([^ !-~]|`)'
FROM   generate_series (1,300) g;  -- ASCII range plus some
```

Assuming server encoding UTF8, to find rows with any non-ASCII characters in the 3 columns:

```
...
WHERE octet_length(concat(a.address_line_1, a.address_line_2, a.address_line_3))
         <> length(concat(a.address_line_1, a.address_line_2, a.address_line_3))
```

This works because all non-ASCII characters are encoded with more than 1 byte in UTF8, hence `octet_length()` reports a higher number than `length()` (alias: `char_length()`). Concatenation with `concat()` defends against possible NULL values.

To also test for the backtick, add:

```
...
OR  concat(a.address_line_1, a.address_line_2, a.address_line_3) LIKE '%`%'
```

Comment: I removed the `regexp_matches` syntax from the SELECT clause but kept it in the WHERE clause, and updated the WHERE clause with a concatenated instance of all three address fields... this has worked perfectly... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `exists`:

```
where exists (select 1 from regexp_matches(a.address_line_1, '[^ !-~]')) or
      exists (select 1 from regexp_matches(a.address_line_2, '[^ !-~]')) or
      exists (select 1 from regexp_matches(a.address_line_3, '[^ !-~]'))
```

Or, more simply:

```
where a.address_line_1 ~ '[^ !-~]' or
      a.address_line_2 ~ '[^ !-~]' or
      a.address_line_3 ~ '[^ !-~]'
```

Comment: This seems to be doing the same thing as above... I know I have multiple rows where there are address fields with invalid characters in any of these three fields, so why is this query pulling the only row with invalid characters in all three fields instead of rows with invalid characters in any of the three?

Comment: @Eliseod'Annunzio . . . That is rather strange.  The connector is `or`, so that should apply to *any* of the three columns.